# Running turtles simultaneously with turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How can I make 4 different turtles move at the same time? Also, how to make a person shape for the `Turtle.shape`method? I know there's a Screen method called `register_shape`, but I couldn't find any documentation on it.

```
def turtles(self, base):
    self.t4.goto(self.tFirst)
    self.t1.goto(self.tSecond)
    self.t2.goto(self.tThird)
    self.t3.goto(self.tHome)
    if base >= 2:
        self.t4.goto(self.tSecond)
        self.t1.goto(self.tThird)
        self.t2.goto(self.tHome)
    if base >= 3:
        self.t4.goto(self.tThird)
        self.t1.goto(self.tHome)
    if base == 4:
        self.t4.goto(self.tHome)
```

`tFirst`, `tSecond` an `tThird` are positions, and `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4` are turtles. I want all of the turtles to move in unison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Multiple Turtles Moving (seemingly) Simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056498/python-multiple-turtles-moving-seemingly-simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation for [register_shape](http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape)

As for your first question, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Making them all move in separate threads would be my first idea, but even then they technically don't move at the same time.  I have never actually used turtle graphics, but just know of the concept.

This does something close to what you are talking about

```
import turtle
import numpy as np

tlist = list()
colorlist = ["red", "green", "black", "blue", "brown"]
for i in xrange(5):
    tlist.append(turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle"))
    tlist[i].color(colorlist[i])
    tlist[i].speed(1)
screen = turtle.getscreen()
for i in xrange(100):
    screen.tracer(1000)
    for t in tlist:
        t.right((np.random.rand(1) - .5) * 180)
        t.forward(int((np.random.rand(1) - .5) * 100))
    screen.update()
```

or

```
import turtle
#import numpy as np
from time import sleep

tlist = list()
colorlist = ["red", "green", "black", "blue", "brown"]
for i in xrange(5):
    tlist.append(turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle"))
    tlist[i].color(colorlist[i])
    tlist[i].speed(1)
screen = turtle.getscreen()
for i in xrange(100):
    screen.tracer(1000)
    for i, t in enumerate(tlist):
        #t.right((np.random.rand(1) - .5) * 180))
        t.right(33 * i)
        #t.forward(int((np.random.rand(1) - .5) * 100))
        t.forward(50 * i)
    sleep(1)
    screen.update()
```

Comment: I thinking of making a sports field graphic with players, so I'd need to make each of them move in different directions at the same time.

Comment: You could also try delaying the animation update so they appear to have moved at the same time [turtle.update](http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html#turtle.update)

Comment: I don't think update will help. Also, I'm running python 3.2, and delay is a screen method, it might have been different in previous versions. I called delay, and it changed the time of the animation, not the time between animations. So a screen.delay(200) took 200 milliseconds but screen.delay(5) took 5, and the turtles still have separately. thx for you help

Comment: You should probably accept answers to all the previous questions people  have helped you with.  Or at least provide feedback as to why you didn't accept them.  People will stop answering your questions if you never accept an answer

Comment: Sorry, I tried what you had suggested, but the update and delay methods didn't appear useful for making the animation seem continuous, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: Where do I go to get numPy for Mac-Lion?

Comment: [here](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X), but I just used it to get random numbers to move and turn by...you can change them to constants if you like.  Just replace the value inside t.right() and t.forward()

Comment: That's brilliant. Cool drawing.

Comment: As I was implementing this idea, I noticed one issue. Everything is simultaneous, but it becomes instantaneous. It appears that in order for the turtles to move simultaneously, they have to move almost instantaneously. Would there be a way to keep them moving together, but not moving at relativistic speeds?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would offer this up as a possibility. I recently wanted to have all my turtles dancing together too and the closest I got was to create a list of all my turtle objects and then iterate over that list.

Admittedly this gets them to move one at a time but they won't make a second move until all have made the first.

I've written a full program here for you merely to demonstrate how it looks. If it's not what you are looking for I do apologise, but at least its a possible solution to another problem for someone else.

```
import turtle
import random
wn = turtle.Screen()

bob = turtle.Turtle()
mary = turtle.Turtle()
fred = turtle.Turtle()
jane = turtle.Turtle()

turtles = [bob, mary, fred, jane]

for move in range(10):
    for item in turtles:
        item.left(random.randrange(-180, 180))
        item.forward(50)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import turtle
import threading

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("red")


class myTurtle (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,init_angle):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.noel = turtle.Turtle()
        self.noel.rt(init_angle)
        self.init_angle = init_angle
    def run(self):
        for self.i in range(self.init_angle,self.init_angle + 9):
            for self.j in range(4):
                self.noel.fd(100)
                self.noel.rt(90)
                self.noel.rt(1)


t1 = myTurtle(0)
t2 = myTurtle(90)

t1.start()
t2.start()
window.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

To make all the turtles move at the same time(if I'm understanding the question correctly) you need to use the `tracer()` method.

```
turtle.tracer(
    (First number is how many frames go by before turtle updates the screen),
    (second number is a delay in milliseconds)
)
```

Because turtle updates the screen every time any turtle moves, tracer is how you get them to all move at the same time. Usually `turtle.tracer(0, 20)` should be fine or `turtle.tracer(1, 20)`.