# How can I move 2 turtles at once in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, turtle-graphics

I want to make a fractal tree in python. I have made the tree, but I want to have 2 turtles or more to draw my fractal tree all at once. Is there a way to do that? I've looked for solutions but none of them is what I really want. Here is my code:

```
import turtle
tree = turtle.Turtle()
tree.ht()
tree.penup()
tree.sety(-200)
tree.left(90)

import turtle
tree0 = turtle.Turtle()
tree0.ht()
tree0.penup()
tree0.sety(-200)
tree0.left(90)

startx = tree.xcor()
starty = tree.ycor()
startx = tree0.xcor()
starty = tree0.ycor()

def fractalright(angle, length, x, y):
    tree.speed(0)
    tree.setx(x)
    tree.sety(y)
    tree.pendown()
    tree.forward(length)
    tree.right(angle)
    length = length - 20
    x = tree.xcor()
    y = tree.ycor()
    if length < 0:
        return
    tree.penup()
    fractalright(angle, length, x, y)
    tree.penup()
    tree.setx(x)
    tree.sety(y)
    tree.left(angle)
    fractalright (-angle, length, x, y)
def fractalleft(angle, length, x, y):
    tree0.speed(0)
    tree0.setx(x)
    tree0.sety(y)
    tree0.pendown()
    tree0.forward(length)
    tree0.right(angle)
    length = length - 20
    x = tree0.xcor()
    y = tree0.ycor()
    if length < 0:
        return
    tree0.penup()
    fractalleft(angle, length, x, y)
    tree0.penup()
    tree0.setx(x)
    tree0.sety(y)
    tree0.left(angle)
    fractalleft (-angle, length, x, y)
```

I am using python 3 and please let me know if you know a solution. Thanks!!

Comment: You mention [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) in the tages, have you looked at the documentation for that, another option is [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), I would recommend looking at them, then trying one out, then if you still have issues come back with those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running turtles simultaneously with turtle graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502492/running-turtles-simultaneously-with-turtle-graphics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to using module `threading` with `turtle` is to not allow additional threads to manipulate the turtles -- they instead queue up their turtle requests and let the main thread process them:

```
import queue
from threading import Thread, active_count
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def forward(turtle, distance):
    graphics.put((turtle.forward, distance))

def right(turtle, angle):
    graphics.put((turtle.right, angle))

def left(turtle, angle):
    graphics.put((turtle.left, angle))

def fractalright(turtle, angle, length):
    forward(turtle, length)

    if length - 20 > 0:
        right(turtle, angle)
        fractalright(turtle, angle, length - 20)
        left(turtle, angle)
        fractalright(turtle, -angle, length - 20)

    forward(turtle, -length)

def fractalleft(turtle, angle, length):
    forward(turtle, length)

    if length - 20 > 0:
        left(turtle, angle)
        fractalleft(turtle, angle, length - 20)
        right(turtle, angle)
        fractalleft(turtle, -angle, length - 20)

    forward(turtle, -length)

def process_queue():
    while not graphics.empty():
        action, argument = graphics.get()
        action(argument)

    if active_count() > 1:
        screen.ontimer(process_queue, 100)

START_X, START_Y = 0, -200

screen = Screen()
screen.mode('logo')  # make starting direction 0 degrees towards top

tree1 = Turtle(visible=False)
tree1.color('green')
tree1.penup()
tree1.goto(START_X, START_Y)
tree1.pendown()

tree2 = Turtle(visible=False)
tree2.color('dark green')
tree2.penup()
tree2.goto(START_X, START_Y)
tree2.pendown()

graphics = queue.Queue(1)  # size = number of hardware threads you have - 1

def fractal1():
    fractalright(tree1, 30, 100)

def fractal2():
    fractalleft(tree2, 30, 100)

thread1 = Thread(target=fractal1)
thread1.daemon = True  # thread dies when main thread (only non-daemon thread) exits.
thread1.start()

thread2 = Thread(target=fractal2)
thread2.daemon = True  # thread dies when main thread (only non-daemon thread) exits.
thread2.start()

process_queue()

screen.exitonclick()
```

We're using the queue module for thread-safe communications.  I rewrote your `fractalright()` and `fractalleft()` functions to minimize the variety of graphics operations they require.

[image]

If all goes correctly, you should see the light green and dark green portions of the tree being drawn independently at the same time.  Your computer needs to have at least a couple of hardware threads available.

Answer (score 1):

Distilling away the details of how you are drawing the trees, the basic task is to execute two instances of some draw function in parallel with different arguments to specify one "left tree" and one "right tree." This basic structure can be implemented as follows:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import time


def draw_function(current_tree):
    # Replace the following lines with what you need to do with turtles
    print("Drawing tree {}".format(current_tree))
    time.sleep(1)


# Replace this with list of tuples of arguments to draw_function specifying
# angle, length, x, y, left vs right, etc.
list_of_trees = ["left_tree", "right_tree"]

my_pool = Pool(2)

results = my_pool.map(draw_function, list_of_trees)

my_pool.close()
my_pool.join()
```

In your case, I'm a little unclear on the distinction between `fractalleft` and `fractalright`, since they appear identical, but that logic should form the basis for your `draw_function`. You should create a separate turtle for each execution of `draw_function`, but note that you needn't re-import turtle.

Comment: I have a question, what do you mean replace this with list of tuples of arguments to draw_function specifying angle, length, x, y, left vs right, etc.

Comment: Let's say your draw_function ends up requiring the arguments angle, length, x, y, and a boolean specifying whether this is a "left" type tree or a "right" type tree. If you have two trees to draw, you could make a list consisting of two tuples, each of which contains the appropriate parameters for one of the trees. The draw_function would then accept and parse that tuple to determine how to draw the tree. Probably even better would be to let draw_function accept a single argument which is an instance of a custom Tree class, which specifies everything you need to draw a tree.